# SSH access requires firewall exception

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my server via ssh, but I can't connect unless I add a firewall exception in my server settings (add an IP address). Is there any way to let any IP address connect? Is this a bad thing to do?

Update:
I get my IP address from the link in WHM "What is your IP?"
[image]

Comment: What IP address do you add and to what server settings?

Comment: show us the output of `iptables -L -v -n` .

Comment: I lookup my IP address and add it to my firewall exceptions. @Iain where do I enter that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could add 0.0.0.0/0 but that would be everything, people *will* try and access your server so it is better to restrict the range.

If you have a static IP get your IP address by typing "whats my ip" into google, then you can enter it directly into the allow rule box.

If your IP is dynamic and changes, you might want to restrict it to your ISP by using the first two digits x.x.0.0/16 (i.e. if your IP is 53.2.18.8 you would put 53.2.0.0/16) perhaps your ISP could give you the address ranges it uses?

I can see you are using cPanel, I have found ConfigServer (CSF plugin at configserver.com) and cPhulk (built in to cPanel) useful to blacklist and prevent brutefotce attempts.

Comment: Sorry as this may seem like a dumb question, but you said people will try to access my server. Are there "bots" that will just try to connect to my server and delete everything? Also, I have a password on the root account of course, but I have unlimited tries to enter the password. So bruteforce seems inevitable. Any way to limit the number of tries?

Comment: @EGHDK there are bots and scanners which will search forl live IPs and then start attempting to log in and connect to services. I have updated my reply